# How to prevent draggable widgets (created with Matrix4 Transform) in a Stack from changing their positions when another draggable widget is added?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, layout

I'm trying to create draggable and resizable widgets (`Matrix4 Gesture Detector` Widget) wrapped inside a `Stack`widget. I'm able to drag and resize the widgets in the way I want them to, but the problem is, when I programatically add another widget to the `Stack`'s children, all the draggable widgets which were previously positioned revert and comes back to the center along with the newly added dragabble widget.

Let's say there are 2 draggable widgets in the `Stack` initially and we also positioned them,

[image]

When I add another widget programatically by tapping on the `Add` button, the positions are lost and every draggable widget appears to the center like this,

[image]

How can I fix this issue and prevent the widgets from not reverting to the center? Here is the code.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: DummyProvider())
      ],
    child: MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
    )
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DummyProvider dummyProvider =
        Provider.of<DummyProvider>(context, listen: true);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: Constants.deviceHeight! * .6,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Stack(
                children: List.generate(
                    dummyProvider.list.length,
                    (index) => Drag(
                          text: Text(dummyProvider.list[index].text,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40)),
                        )),
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                dummyProvider.addToList(DraggableText(
                    id: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
                    text: String.fromCharCodes(List.generate(
                        5, (index) => Random().nextInt(33) + 89))));
              },
              child: Text("Add"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`DraggableText`class,

```
class DraggableText {
  String id = '';
  String text = '';
  FontWeight fontWeight = FontWeight.normal;
  FontStyle fontStyle = FontStyle.normal;
  TextDecoration fontDecoration = TextDecoration.none;
  Matrix4 position = Matrix4.identity();
  DraggableText({required this.id, required this.text});
}
```

The provider that has all the draggable widget,

```
class DummyProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<DraggableText> list = [];
  String currentText = '';

  void addToList(DraggableText text) {
    list.add(text);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The dragabble text widget using Matrix4 Gesture Detector Package,

```
class Drag extends StatelessWidget {
  final Text text;
  const Drag({required this.text});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ValueNotifier<Matrix4> notifier = ValueNotifier(Matrix4.identity());
    return MatrixGestureDetector(
      onMatrixUpdate: (m, tm, sm, rm) {
        notifier.value = m;
        print("$m $tm $sm $rm");
      },
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: notifier,
        builder: (ctx, child) {
          return Transform(
            transform: notifier.value,
            child: Center(
  

        child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Transform.scale(
                scale: 1,
                origin: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                child: GestureDetector(
                    child:
                        Container(color: Colors.blueAccent, child: text)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);}}
```

Comment: you need to assign key to drag item, so they are handle in different state

Comment: Can you please post as an answer with a code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with generator, it is refreshing the list including the positions, every setState it is creating newList. I added extra property to model class to handle it and some extra-methods at notifier while testing the issue, this may help in the future.

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: DummyProvider())],
    child: const MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: constraints.maxHeight * .6,
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Consumer<DummyProvider>(
                  builder: (context, value, child) => Stack(
                    children: value.list
                        .map(
                          (d) => Drag(
                            key: ValueKey(d.id),
                            notifier: d.notifier!,
                            callBack: (
                              Matrix4 matrix,
                            ) {
                              // print("${matrix.row0.a}  ${matrix.row1.a}");
                              print(matrix);
                            },
                            text: Text(
                              d.text,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  final provider = context.read<DummyProvider>();
                  provider.addToList(
                    DraggableText(
                      id: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
                      text: String.fromCharCodes(
                        List.generate(5, (index) => Random().nextInt(33) + 89),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: Text("Add"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Drag extends StatelessWidget {
  final Text text;
  final ValueNotifier<Matrix4> notifier;
  final Function callBack;

  const Drag({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.callBack,
    required this.notifier,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MatrixGestureDetector(
      onMatrixUpdate: (m, tm, sm, rm) {
        notifier.value = m;
        // print("$m $tm $sm $rm");
        callBack(notifier.value);
      },
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: notifier,
        builder: (ctx, child) {
          print("${notifier.value.row0.a}  ${notifier.value.row1.a}");

          return Transform(
            transform: notifier.value,
            child: Center(
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Transform.scale(
                    scale: 1,
                    origin: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        child: text,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DraggableText {
  String id = '';
  String text = '';
  FontWeight fontWeight = FontWeight.normal;
  FontStyle fontStyle = FontStyle.normal;
  TextDecoration fontDecoration = TextDecoration.none;
  Matrix4 position = Matrix4.identity();
  ValueNotifier<Matrix4>? notifier;
  DraggableText({
    required this.id,
    required this.text,
  }) {
    this.notifier = this.notifier ?? ValueNotifier(Matrix4.identity());
  }
}

class DummyProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<DraggableText> list = [];
  String currentText = '';

  void addToList(DraggableText text) {
    list.add(text);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updatePosition(int index, Matrix4 position) {
    list[index].position = position;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updatePositionByItem(DraggableText text, Matrix4 position) {
    list.firstWhere((element) => element == text).position = position;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in stateless:

```
class Drag extends StatelessWidget {
  final Text text;

  const Drag({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

or in stateful:

```
class Drag extends StatefulWidget {
  final Text text;

  Drag({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => DragState();
}

class DragState extends State<Drag> {
```

use it with:

```
Drag(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  text:
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but sadly this isn't working :(